# How To Read Dictionary Data in a mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, stored-procedures

I have dictionary type data in this method

```
public Dictionary<string, string> TracingFailed(string AgentIp, string AgentId, string SessionId)
{

    Dictionary<string, string> LogData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    LogData.Add("Agent_Id", AgentId);
    LogData.Add("login_time", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    LogData.Add("login_response", "Login Successfully");
    LogData.Add("SessionId", SessionId);
    LogData.Add("IP_Address", AgentIp);
    LogData.Add("NLogin_time", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    return LogData;
}
```

And I have a table of column values presented in key names. Suggest me How to create a `mysql` procedure so that this data can be posted to the procedure and inserted into table. Suggest me. please

Here I am calling this method.

```
Dictionary<string, string> LogData = objDal.TracingFailed(AgentIp.ToString(), modelData.AgentId.ToString(), SessionId);
objDal.InsertLog(LogData);
```

Method Definition. of Insert lOG.

```
public void InsertLog(Dictionary<string, string> LogData)
        {
            string Procedure = "SP_LoginLog";
            ExecuteNonQuery(Procedure, CommandType.StoredProcedure,new MySqlParameter[] {new MySqlParameter("@columnName",LogData.Keys),new MySqlParameter("@ColumnValue",LogData.Values)});

        }
```

For this I have created a procedure.

SP_LoginLog

```
Delimiter //
create procedure SP_LoginLog(in ColumnName varchar(300),in ColumnValue varchar(300))
begin
set @sql=concat("insert into login_log("'ColumnName'")values("'ColumnValue'")");
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
end //
Delimiter;
```

Comment: Try To pass data using string array that will be easy to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way.You can store this data to an **xml** file like

```
XElement el= new XElement(LoadData.Key,LoadData.value);
```

now you can send this as **text** parameter to your procedure.There U can extract **xml** data in a ***temp table*** and then you can insert it.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server there is something called Table Value Parameter, but MySql does not have this. So you can try creating a temporary table and then using a LOAD DATA as shown [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to push the data into the temporary table. Then pass the name of the temporary table into your stored procedure.

Comment: passing name of temporary table will be enough to differentiate about column name and values??

Comment: In your stored procedure you will have to know the name of the columns of the temp table to read it. I cannot see any other way to accomplish this.